# Microsoft Graph API shares / drives filter deleted files

Tags: api, sharepoint, graph, onedrive

I am using the Graph API to get Files from Sharepoint.
Somehow I get deleted files in the response without any flag where i can filter.

I mean, i do not want to see files that are in the Recycle bin.

Is there a filter or something similar?

'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/u!sss/root?expand=children';
or
'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!xxx/root:/Dokumente/xxx/children';

Answer (score 0):

There are no filters available to filter deleted files. For listing deleted files/folders, you can use [delta query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) as it enables applications to discover newly created, updated, or deleted driveItems.

The initial request to the delta query function (no delta or skip token) will return the resources that currently exist in the collection. The final page of items will include the **@odata.deltaLink** property, which provides the URL that can be used later to retrieve changes since the current set of items.

Endpoint：

```
GET /sites/{siteId}/drive/root/delta
```

Comment: Is there anything else I can help with regarding this issue? You can comment us at any time and we will continue to follow up. Thanks, Carl Zhao

Comment: Hi Carl Zhao. I am struggling with getting the name of the deleted file with the delta query. I have tried to do a get request using the id coming from the delta response, but I get 404 for deleted items. I am running delta query against the SharePoint site drive.